# Apache2 LocationMatch allow an index for login but nothing else?

Tags: apache-2.4, regex

I want to allow `/myapp` and `/myapp/` but disallow everything else. How do I configure this? I tried this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/myapp/.+$">
LDAP here
</LocationMatch>
```

Which I would assume would NOT hit `/myapp` or `/myapp/`, but it appears that captures those URLs as well.

If I do

```
<LocationMatch "^/myapp/specificsubdirectory/.*$">
LDAP here
</LocationMatch>
```

Then this works, but I want to block off all specific subdirectories in the app.

Comment: are you sure that you don't have a nasty rewrite somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryIndex is applied before LocationMatch, rewriting the location to end with the directory index file (index.html, index.php and so on). Your pattern

```
^/myapp/.+$
```

matches, because it's actually applied to

```
/myapp/index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression is wrong. Try a [`pcretest(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pcretest):

```
$ pcretest
PCRE version 8.37 2015-04-28

  re> /^\/myapp\/.+$/
data> /myapp
No match
data> /myapp/
No match
data>
  re> /^\/myapp(|\/)$/
data> /myapp
 0: /myapp
 1:
data> /myapp/
 0: /myapp/
 1: /
data> /myapp/foo
No match
```

So a working `<LocationMatch>` directive would be:

```
<LocationMatch "^/myapp(|/)$">
```

Comment: That seems to match the opposite of what I need.

Comment: How so? You say "I want to allow /myapp and /myapp/ but disallow everything else". The regex above matches `/myapp` and `/myapp/`. Or do you mean you want to **restrict** everything else (using LDAP auth)?

Comment: @StefanKendall Care to reword your requirement so I can try to provide an appropriate answer?